# Node Postgress insert multiple value?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

How to use format or any other medium to create query for inserting multiple values.

pg, pg-format are being used in project

```
rows = [[200,"http://localhost:3000/product",null,[{url:"www.someurl.com", name: "Test"},{url:"www.someurl1.com", name: "Test1"}]],[400,"http://localhost:3000/user",null,[{url:"www.someurl3.com", name: "1Test"},{url:"www.someurl2.com", name: "1Test1"}]]]

columns = ['code', 'url', 'additional', 'response']
const query1 = format(`INSERT INTO ${table_name} (${columns.join(', ')}) VALUES %L returning id`, rows);
```

query1 is getting formatted to

```
INSERT INTO testtable (code, url, additional, response) VALUES ('200','http://localhost:3000/product',NULL, ('{"url":"www.someurl.com","name": "Test"}}}'::jsonb, '{"url":"www.someurl.com","name":"customer"}}'::jsonb),'200','http://localhost:3000/user',NULL,'{"id":"61e541b9700bb8c4cbe008b8","status":"queued"}'::jsonb) returning id
```

Values are getting changed two values types should be created with:

```
(code, url, additional, response), (code, url, additional, response)
```

But it followed:

```
(code, url, additional), (response, code, url, additional)
```

Not sure what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can write your rows like this:

```
rows = [
  [200,"http://localhost:3000/product", null, `${JSON.stringify([{url:"www.someurl.com", name: "Test"},{url:"www.someurl1.com", name: "Test1"}])}::jsonb`],
  [400,"http://localhost:3000/user", null, `${JSON.stringify([{url:"www.someurl3.com", name: "1Test"},{url:"www.someurl2.com", name: "1Test1"}])}::jsonb`]
]
```

explicitly telling `pg-format` that they're jsonb values.